# NewtonSoft Deserialization to JObject very slow

Tags: .net, performance, .net-core, json.net

I was just trying to find out why some code is a bit slow and got to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace SerializerGames
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write File");
            await File.WriteAllTextAsync("xxx.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Large(6)),
                new UTF8Encoding(false));

            Console.WriteLine("reading into string");
            var content = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("xxx.json");
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Newtonsoft Deserializing into typed object");
                await using var ms = new MemoryStream(content);
                using var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr);
                var js = new JsonSerializer();
                sw.Restart();
                var xxx = js.Deserialize<Large>(jtr);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine(xxx.StringValue);
            }

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Newtonsoft Deserializing into JObject");
                await using var ms = new MemoryStream(content);
                using var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr);
                var js = new JsonSerializer();
                sw.Restart();
                var xxx = js.Deserialize<JToken>(jtr);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine(xxx["StringValue"].Value<string>());
            }
        }
    }

    public class Large
    {
        private static readonly Random rng = new Random();

        public Large()
        {
        }

        public Large(int depthDoGo)
        {
            if (depthDoGo <= 0)
            {
                StringValue = rng.Next().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayValue = new[]
                {
                    new Large(depthDoGo - 1),
                    new Large(depthDoGo - 1),
                    new Large(depthDoGo - 1),
                    new Large(depthDoGo - 1),
                    new Large(depthDoGo - 1)
                };
                Kiddies = new Dictionary<string, Large>(
                    new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1)),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1)),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1)),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1)),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1)),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1)),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, Large>(rng.Next().ToString(), new Large(depthDoGo - 1))
                    }
                );
            }
        }

        public string StringValue { get; set; }
        public Large[] ArrayValue { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Large> Kiddies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The JToken (also JObject) deserialization is three to five times slower than the typed deserialization.
I'm using JToken in a large object to denote bits I just pass through (cosmos db to http client) and use explicit types for the fields I need to read in my web api.

The fields that I use JToken for are also not fields I can just define classes for. They are a kind of opaque payload that changes in ways I can't control.

So, is there a way that doesn't slow down newtonsoft so much?

Comment: I recommend you run each test multiple times, and take the average.  Startup effects may be dominating here.  You may also want to permute the order in which the two tests are done, and kate the average.  That being said, it's known that parsing to `JObject` can be slower than deserializing -- see https://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/ which states, *Parsing generic JSON to a JSON.net JObject ... is slower (~20%) than reading that data in to a defined class type.*  A 3-5X slowdown is surprising though, have you profiled?

Comment: *So, is there a way that doesn't slow down newtonsoft so much?* - From [Eric Lippert's blog](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): ***Use a profiler or other analysis tool to determine empirically where the bottleneck is before you start investigating alternatives.*** You're more likely to get help if you can profile the two approaches and let us know what specifically what the bottleneck is with `JToken`.